# I'm cronstruction python based api calls to aws and can't figure out a logging problem

Tags: amazon-ec2, python-3.9

This script works, however I can't get it to record the linux user who's executing the script into the log. I'm not taking credit for this code it's code that ChatGPT wrote. I know it has something to do with 'user' but I've brought this to the AI in so many contexts and it always get's it wrong. I am hoping to have a good python programmer suggest a fix. Any ideas?

```
import os
import sys
import boto3
import logging
import getpass
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/opt/tango/aws/awsapiBUILD_RULE_in_SG.log',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.INFO
)

def create_session():
    access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )
    return session

def create_sg_rule(group_id, ip_protocol, from_port, to_port, cidr_ip, description):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    user = getpass.getuser()

    try:
        response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
            GroupId=group_id,
            IpPermissions=[
                {
                    'IpProtocol': ip_protocol,
                    'FromPort': from_port,
                    'ToPort': to_port,
                    'IpRanges': [
                        {
                            'CidrIp': cidr_ip,
                            'Description': description
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        )
        print(f'Ingress rule added to security group {group_id}')
        extra = defaultdict(lambda: 'unknown', {'user': user})
        logging.info(
            f'Ingress rule added to security group {group_id}',
            extra=extra
        )
        output = {"success": True}
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f'Error: {e}, User: {user}'
        print(error_message)
        extra = defaultdict(lambda: 'unknown', {'user': user})
        logging.error(
            error_message,
            extra=extra
        )
        output = {"error": str(e)}
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add ingress rule to AWS security group.')
    parser.add_argument('--group-id', type=str, required=True, help='The ID of the security group to modify')
    parser.add_argument('--ip-protocol', type=str, required=True, help='The IP protocol for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--from-port', type=int, required=True, help='The starting port for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--to-port', type=int, required=True, help='The ending port for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--cidr-ip', type=str, required=True, help='The CIDR IP range to allow access from')
    parser.add_argument('--description', type=str, required=True, help='The description of the ingress rule')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    session = create_session()
    create_sg_rule(args.group_id, args.ip_protocol, args.from_port, args.to_port, args.cidr_ip, args.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

This 100% works. I'm still trying to tweak logging and print output to display more info but it's working as needed in this form. No I didn't figure it out. I just finally found a way to ask AI the right question.

```
import os
import sys
import boto3
import logging
import getpass
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/opt/tango/aws/awsapiBUILD_RULE_in_SG.log',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.INFO
)

def create_session():
    access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )
    return session

def create_sg_rule(group_id, ip_protocol, from_port, to_port, cidr_ip, description):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    user = getpass.getuser()

    try:
        response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
            GroupId=group_id,
            IpPermissions=[
                {
                    'IpProtocol': ip_protocol,
                    'FromPort': from_port,
                    'ToPort': to_port,
                    'IpRanges': [
                        {
                            'CidrIp': cidr_ip,
                            'Description': description
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        )
        print(f'Ingress rule added to security group {group_id}')
        extra = defaultdict(lambda: 'unknown', {'user': user})
        logging.info(
            f'Ingress rule added to security group {group_id}, User: {user}',
            extra=extra
        )
        output = {"success": True}
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f'Error: {e}, User: {user}'
        print(error_message)
        extra = defaultdict(lambda: 'unknown', {'user': user})
        logging.error(
            error_message,
            extra=extra
        )
        output = {"error": str(e)}
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add ingress rule to AWS security group.')
    parser.add_argument('--group-id', type=str, required=True, help='The ID of the security group to modify')
    parser.add_argument('--ip-protocol', type=str, required=True, help='The IP protocol for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--from-port', type=int, required=True, help='The starting port for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--to-port', type=int, required=True, help='The ending port for the ingress rule')
    parser.add_argument('--cidr-ip', type=str, required=True, help='The CIDR IP range to allow access from')
    parser.add_argument('--description', type=str, required=True, help='The description of the ingress rule')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    session = create_session()
    create_sg_rule(args.group_id, args.ip_protocol, args.from_port, args.to_port, args.cidr_ip, args.description)
```